# Расположенном или расположенному?

Tags: правописание

Как правильно:

> сведения об объекте недвижимости,
> расположенном по адресу

или

> сведения об объекте недвижимости,
> расположенномУ по адресу

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: "сведения об объекте недвижимости, расположенном по адресу". Согласование в П.п.